# php passing pdf content to an iframe using pdftk

Tags: php, html, pdf, iframe, pdftk

I am generating a pdf using pdftk into an iframe with:

```
<iframe src="data:application/pdf, <?php passthru('pdftk example.pdf output -'); ?>"> </iframe>
```

However the browser (chrome) reports:

> "The file was damaged and could not be repaired"

What am I doing wrong?

If I have a separate file, and reference that within the iframe it works fine.  the separate filecontent is:

```
<?php
header("Content-type: application/pdf");
passthru('pdftk example.pdf output -');
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

According to https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.passthru.php, the `passthru` function is intended to return binary data. I'm not sure if there's enough room in the `src` attribute to fit all that binary data.

Take that PHP snippet, save as a `something.php` file, and use that as the `src="something.php"` - that should work.